# xml loading in java with x path

Tags: java, xpath

This is the code of my program i want to load xml "test" . When i build this i get loaded  and no of nodes in "0".is there is a problem in loading or x path. I am using eclipse. please help me to fix this issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<resourses>
    <resourse status="1">
        <name>resourse1</name>
        <type>1</type>
    </resourse>

    <resourse  status="2">
        <name>resourse2</name>
        <type>2</type>
    </resourse>

          <resourse  status="3">
        <name>resourse3</name>
        <type>3</type>
    </resourse>

</resourses>





public class xml_l 
{
public static void main(String[] args)

throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException,
IOException, XPathExpressionException 

{
DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory =DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);

DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

Document doc = builder.parse("/home/user/test/test.xml");
if (doc==null)
{

System.out.println("not loaded");   

}
else
{

    System.out.println(" loaded "); 
}

XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();


XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//resourse[status =1]/name/text()"); 

Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
System.out.println(nodes.getLength());

for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++)                                        // nodes.getLength()
{
System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());

}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have an '@' in front of the attribute to inform xPath you are looking for an attribute.

```
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//resourse[@status=1]/name/text()");
```

Not

```
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//resourse[status=1]/name/text()");
```